# pointers between dynamic structs memory

Tags: c

I am trying to solve a little problem from my university, but i get into trouble completing it.

The task is to write a code defining all the data structures and create a link between them using pointers and mallocs.

ASSIGNMENT :

There are 3 blocks. 
1) is a static block with 2 fields, 1st field is an integer, and a second field points to another block.

2) a block with 2 fields. 1st field points to the first block and 2nd field points to the 3rd block.

3) a block with 2 fields. 1st field is an integer and 2nd field points to the first block.

I have started creating the code and making the links but i keep getting errors which i cant seem to find thier logic.

```
struct A;
struct B;
struct C;
typedef struct {
int element;
struct A * pointer3;
}C;

typedef struct {
    struct A * pointer 1;
    struct C * pointer 2;
}B;


typedef struct {
    int element;
    struct B * pointer 0;
 }A;

int main (){
    A a;
    a.pointer0 = (B*)malloc(sizeof(B));
```

I have reached farther then that, but the problem i get is in the last line.
Gives me the error warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type

Comment: how do you expect `struct A * pointer 1;` to be valid?

Comment: There is no `struct A` formal definition in this code. Nor is there a `struct B`, nor `struct C`. There are only forward decls of all of the above. Then, there are untagged structures *typedef* to `A` , `B`, and `C` respectively. In short: there is nothing here to indicate `struct A` is equivalent to `A`, etc. Therefore, assigning a (ill-advised) cast to `B*` to something that is supposed to be `struct B*` makes no sense to the compiler, and it's warning you about it.

Comment: When I google your error message, I find many pages that explains the problem well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Question: What does `struct A` look like? Answer: Your compiler has no idea because you never defined it.

You're assuming forward-declaring a structure type, then formally declaring a typedef alias to a structure where the alias *name* (but not tag) is the same as the structure *tag* (with no name) will resolve. It won't. You have to do that yourself.

Start with simple. Get rid of the type aliases entirely. And get rid of any unnecessary forward decls as well (B and C) What would it look like?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct A; // fwd decl

struct C 
{
    int element;
    struct A *pointer3; // uses fwd decl
};

struct B
{
    struct A *pointer1; // uses fwd decl 
    struct C *pointer2; // uses prior def
};

struct A // resolves fwd decl
{
    int element;
    struct B *pointer0; // uses prior def
};

int main() 
{
    struct A a;
    a.pointer0 = malloc(sizeof(struct B));
}
```

That works (in the most optimistic definition of the term). If you want to use typedef aliases, you can add them in now. For example, here is all three structures both tagged and aliased.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct A;
typedef struct A A;

typedef struct C 
{
    int element;
    A *pointer3;
} C;

typedef struct B
{
    A *pointer1;
    C *pointer2;
} B;

struct A 
{
    int element;
    B *pointer0;
};

int main() 
{
    A a;
    a.pointer0 = malloc(sizeof(B));
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answers, i have it all much clearer now!